# How terraform refresh & apply work in a scenario when the name of a resource is modified in .tf file?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In the below scenario, could someone confirm what the terraform refresh & apply work?

1. Initially a user has created a **Security Group** by giving value to the "**name**" property as "**sg-123**" as shown in below code. Then the user ran **terraform apply** command which created a Security Group in AWS Cloud.

   resource "aws_security_group" "mySgGroup" {
   name = "sg-123"
   . . . . .
   }
2. Then the user came back to the same .tf file and changed the value of name property **from sg-123 to sg-456** as shown in below code. Then the user ran **terraform apply** command.

   resource "aws_security_group" "mySgGroup" {
   name = "sg-456"
   . . . . .
   }
3. Now what is going to happen in the above scenario? Will terraform just modifies the name of the existing Security Group in the Cloud Infrastructure to **sg-456** (or) will it create a brand new Security Group with name "**sg-456**"?
   I think the Terraform will just rename the name of the existing Security Group instead of creating a brand new Security Group. **But my question is- how the Terraform determine that it should just modify the name of the existing Security Group**?
   Why Terraform will not create a new Security Group with new name and delete the existing Security Group with name: **sg-123**?

Please help with this question.

Comment: It depends, some resources can be modified in place, some have to be replaced. That's what `terraform plan` tells you.

Comment: This depends completely on the capabilities and limitations of the underlying resource and the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update the `name` attribute of an `aws_security_group` in Terraform from "sg-123" to "sg-456" and run `terraform apply`, here's what happens under the hood, due to AWS and Terraform's behavior:

1. **Immutable `name` Attribute**: In AWS, the name of a standard security group is immutable once the group is created. This states that you cannot update the name of an existing security group directly. If you need a security group with a different name, a new security group needs to be created.
2. **Terraform's Actions**: Given this limitation, Terraform's approach when you change the `name` property of an `aws_security_group` resource and apply your configuration is twofold:

   - It will **create a new Security Group** with the new name "sg-456".
   - It will **delete the old Security Group** with the name "sg-123", assuming there are no dependencies blocking the deletion (such as instances still associated with the security group).
3. **State Management**: Terraform manages your infrastructure's state through a state file, tracking the IDs and attributes of managed resources. When you modify your Terraform configuration and apply these changes, Terraform compares the desired state (your configuration files) against the actual state (information in the state file and the real cloud infrastructure). For changes that require a resource to be recreated (like changing an immutable attribute), Terraform decides on a strategy, typically "create before destroy" or "destroy before create," based on the resource and context. For an `aws_security_group`'s `name` change, Terraform opts for creating the new group before destroying the old one, if possible, ensuring that your infrastructure aligns with your specified configuration.

This behavior ensures your infrastructure is always in sync with your Terraform configurations, albeit with the necessary steps to respect cloud provider constraints like immutability of certain resource attributes.

Comment: Thank you @Sarangan for your detailed answer. Here the name is a Immutable field. But if the user changes the value of a Mutable field, then it will just update the value of that field in the real cloud infrastructure instead of recreating a new resource right ?

Comment: For mutable fields, Terraform's default behavior is to issue an update in place, assuming the underlying cloud provider supports modifying the resource in the manner specified. This can include changes to resource configurations such as security group rules, tags, and other properties that do not inherently require the creation of a new resource instance

Comment: Please let me know what happens in below scenario:
1.User has created ONE "AWS EC2 Instance" Resource through Terraform.
2.After that the same user created 2nd "EC2 Instance" manually in AWS Console. Terraform doesn't know about this 2nd EC2 Instance.
3.Then the user ran "terraform refresh" command from CLI and after this will the Terraform fetches BOTH the EC2 Instances to the "tfstate" file or it will NOT fetch the 2nd instance? If "terraform refresh" does not fetch the 2nd Instance(manually created), how does the terraform will know that the 2nd Instance is not created through terraform?